# How to test is a file on ftp is newer or older than a local file?

Tags: file, ftp

`-nt`and `-ot` are available for comparing file time in bash. Is there a command that can help compare a ftp file is older or newer than a local file? Thanks.

Comment: In what FTP? Do you mean command-line `ftp` client? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to compare which one is newer/older between a file from a ftp server and a local file.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. "Compare" is probably not your goal, I assume you want to do something answer comparing the timestamps. And again, what "FTP" do you use?

Comment: "a ftp file" means a file from a ftp server. Compare the timestamp of a file on a ftp server and a local file and return which one is newer or old is what I need.